# Coveo Wildcard Search Not working

Tags: coveo

I wanted to enable Wild Card Search in my Coveo JavaScript Search Framework (Coveo - 4.0.222.0 On Premise) , I had added the attributes  data-enable-query-syntax="true" and data-enable-wildcards="true" for my CoveoSearchbox. Still its not working am i missing something ?

Comment: Are you able to share your Browser Console logs? Check if there are any JavaScript errors too

Comment: Hi Julius , I was said by coveo support team that our version doesnt support wildcard search